# Maui Maps Exception Unhandled

Tags: android, maps, maui

Im trying to add a map to my application, when i add this to my mainpage.xaml file its throwing an exception unhandedled and i have no clue why.

```
`<maps:Map>
    <x:Arguments>
        <maps:MapSpan>
            <x:Arguments>
                <sensors:Location>
                    <x:Arguments>
                        <x:Double>36.9628066</x:Double>
                        <x:Double>-122.0194722</x:Double>
                    </x:Arguments>
                </sensors:Location>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
            </x:Arguments>
        </maps:MapSpan>
    </x:Arguments>
</maps:Map>`
```

Ive added the nuget packages and was following the documentation on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map?view=net-maui-8.0#pins

this is my full xaml code:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:maps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui/maps"
             xmlns:sensors="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maui.Devices.Sensors;assembly=Microsoft.Maui.Essentials"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:J2MobilePClock"
             x:Class="J2MobilePClock.MainPage"
             Title="Punch In">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:PinDataService x:Key="pinDataService" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem
            Order="Secondary"
            Text="Add Company" 
            Clicked="BtnOpenCamera_Clicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem
            Order="Secondary"
            Text="Delete Company" 
            Clicked="BtnDeleteCompany_Clicked"/>
        <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Text="Refresh" Clicked="BtnRefresh_Clicked" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Picker x:Name="companyPicker" Title="Select Company" />
            <Label x:Name="uuidLabel" Text="UUID: " />
            <Button x:Name="BtnLocation" Clicked="BtnLocation_Clicked" Text="Punch In" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>

            <maps:Map>
                <x:Arguments>
                    <maps:MapSpan>
                        <x:Arguments>
                            <sensors:Location>
                                <x:Arguments>
                                    <x:Double>36.9628066</x:Double>
                                    <x:Double>-122.0194722</x:Double>
                                </x:Arguments>
                            </sensors:Location>
                            <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                            <x:Double>0.01</x:Double>
                        </x:Arguments>
                    </maps:MapSpan>
                </x:Arguments>
            </maps:Map>

            <Label x:Name="Loc"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>`
```

Basically tried adding a map following the documentation and its throwing an exception

Comment: On what platform are you seeing this? Did you add the initialization line in your MauiProgram and with a working API key if needed?